# Cheatsheets for Views in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

Hi I am working for a week with android studio.
Is there any cheatsheet for the properties of views (buttons, editText, TextViews etc.)?

Something similar like these:
https://websitesetup.org/css3-cheat-sheet/
https://bootstrap-cheatsheet.themeselection.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found

1. [https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/cs65/cheatsheets/Common-Android-Views-Cheat-Sheet.pdf](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Esergey/cs65/cheatsheets/Common-Android-Views-Cheat-Sheet.pdf)
2. https://dev.to/rohitk570/common-android-views-cheat-sheet-2np2
3. https://alvinalexander.com/android/android-cheat-sheet-main-concepts/
4. https://medium.com/@ryanstewartalex/basic-android-development-cheat-sheet-58d501dabb3f

and this one is pretty good

5. https://cheatography.com/tag/android/
6. https://gist.github.com/ahmedlhanafy/87f8eab5787d956aec9e

Comment: this is so helpful, I am so glad you found these things as I am having a hard time to look at these resources. Thank you!